# How does this work in computing the depth map?

Tags: google-maps, dictionary, directx, shader, depth

From this site: http://www.catalinzima.com/?page_id=14

I've always been confused about how the depth map is calculated.

The vertex shader function calculates position as follows:

```
VertexShaderOutput VertexShaderFunction(VertexShaderInput input)

{

    VertexShaderOutput output;

    float4 worldPosition = mul(input.Position, World);

    float4 viewPosition = mul(worldPosition, View);

    output.Position = mul(viewPosition, Projection);

    output.TexCoord = input.TexCoord;                            //pass the texture coordinates further

    output.Normal =mul(input.Normal,World);                   //get normal into world space

    output.Depth.x = output.Position.z;

    output.Depth.y = output.Position.w;

    return output;

}
```

What are output.Position.z and output.Position.w? I'm not sure as to the maths behind this.

And in the pixel shader there is this line: output.Depth = input.Depth.x / input.Depth.y;

So output.Depth is output.Position.z / outputPOsition.w? Why do we do this?

Finally in the point light shader (http://www.catalinzima.com/?page_id=55) to convert this output to be a position the code is:

```
 //read depth

    float depthVal = tex2D(depthSampler,texCoord).r;

    //compute screen-space position

    float4 position;

    position.xy = input.ScreenPosition.xy;

    position.z = depthVal;

    position.w = 1.0f;

    //transform to world space

    position = mul(position, InvertViewProjection);

    position /= position.w;
```

again I don't understand this. I sort of see why we use InvertViewProjection as we multiply by the view projection previously, but the whole z and now w being made to equal 1, after which the whole position is divided by w confuses me quite a bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To understand this completely, you'll need to understand how the algebra that  underpins 3D transforms works. SO does not really help (or I don't know how to use it) to do matrix math, so it'll have to be without fancy formulaes. Here is some high level explanation though:

If you look closely, you'll notice that all transformations that happen to a vertex position (from model to world to view to clip coordinates) happens to be using 4D vectors. That's right. 4D. Why, when we live in a 3D world ? Because in that 4D representation, all the transformations we usually want to do to vertices are expressible as a matrix multiplication. This is *not* the case if we stay in 3D representation. And matrix multiplications are what a GPU is good at.

What does a vertex in 3D correspond to in 4D ? This is where it gets interesting. The `(x, y, z)` point corresponds to the line `(a.x, a.y, a.z, a)`. We can grab any point on this line to do the math we need, and we usually pick the easiest one, `a=1` (that way, we don't have to do any multiplication, just set `w=1`).

So that answers pretty much all the math you're looking at. To project a 3D point in 4D we set w=1, to get back a component from a 4D vector, that we want to compare against our standard sizes in 3D, we have to divide that component by w.

This coordinate system, if you want to dive deeper, is called `homogeneous coordinates`.